# How to show DialogFragment from Fragment without null pointers due to fragment is not attached to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an issue with showing DialogFragment inside Fragment. It does not matter what I try, I cannot get it to work everytime.

My layout consist of activity with navigation drawer and inside activity I am showing fragments. On those fragments I must show DialogFragment but for that, I must get context/application context/activity/whatever (depends on current year and weather) to show it.

In most cases it works ok but sometimes, even if fragment is constantly showed to user (no configuration changes or anything) it sometimes happen that fragment is not attached. I am getting that error in production as well so it is not just my device.

Good practice for that would be to check with method isAdded() and if activity is not attached then do nothing. I am not sure why this is good practice because users would not be happy if they loose their work since "save dialog" will not be shown just because Google is giving good practices as terrible ones!

So far I have this (among million combinations) inside my fragment:

```
private void showStoreDialog() {
    if (someConditionIsOk) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getString(R.string.someText));
        sb.append(MINIMUM_LENGTH);
        sb.append(getString(R.string.someText2));

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Exception occures on this line: sb.append(getString(R.string.someText));

```
Cause: android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:614)   
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:678)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:700)
solutions.lunalabs.gpsracer.fragments.RecordingFragment.showStoreDialoglog (RecordingFragment.java:152)
```

I know I could solve this by routing through activity with callbacks but I do not want this because I should route all dialogs through activity even if it is needed only in one fragment. Is there a safe solution to this?

Thank you!